# Constant current regulator enable when current and voltage reached

Tags: constant-current, linear-regulator

I have constant current regulator which consists of one transistor, two diodes,  enable transistor (1.5k ohm) and resistor connected from emitter to GND (~15-20ohm) as visible in schematic. It limits current up to 80mA.  Base is enabled when there is only 0.8-1.2mA. I want to fully enable transistor when there is reached 6-7V and at least 6-10mA. How could this be done?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what you want is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the voltage at the enable pin, then a simple solution would be as follows: connect a 5.6 or 6.3V zener diode in series with the Enable resistor. The zener diode will not begin to conduct until the enable voltage reaches 5.6V plus 0.6V for the base-emitter drop of the transistor. Thus the contant current sink will begin not work until the enable voltage is 6.2V.